# sending files with TClientDataSets

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, tclientdataset, datasnap

How do i send files using TClientDataSet?

i am using Delphi2010

thanks

vladimir.

My appologies for the confusion, my intention is to send/tranfer pdf files from one TCLientDataSet to Onother... we are using MIDAS...
thanks

Comment: Can you explain your question? To me it seems that sending file has nothing to do with a TClientDataSet. Do you want to put a binary file in a field? Do you want to send a file over e-mail?

Comment: I think he has a streaming/syncing mechanism/link based on tclientdataset, and wants to synchronize files over that link

Comment: -1 Sorry... I don't get it.  Are you trying to send files from two TClientDataSet located within the same (client) application, between application server and client or between two application clients?  I suggest you to spend some time writing your question if you want someone to spend time answering.

Comment: thanks for the remark jachguate, the idea is to send files from application server to client using TClientDataSet, i am trying to send a pdf file...

thanks guys.

Answer (score 3):

If your files are saved in one of the fields of ClientDataset as BLOB data, and your ClientDataset is connected to a remote DatasetProvider using DataSnap, then just calling TClientDataset.ApplyUpdate is enough to send the changed data from client to DataSnap server.

If your ClientDataset just stores file name, and file content is not saved into database, then you should upload the file to server separately.
To upload the file to server, you can define a server method which takes a stream as its parameter, and call it from your client application.

If you don't know how to add a server method to your DataSnap 2010 server, then I suggest you read Bob Swart's "[Delphi 2010 DataSnap: Your data where you want it, how you want it](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/40356)"

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to move client datasets from machine to machine.  Just use TClientDataSet.SaveToFile to write it to a file, and send the file using whatever transport suits you.  Use LoadFromFile on the receiver to load the CDS back.  I would suspect there's a SaveToStream as well, which would allow you to write it to RAM and send it over a socket.

Comment: -1 vladimir indicates he is using MIDAS (which is now called DataSnap) as his transport.

Comment: He indicated he was using MIDAS after my original post. He hasn't specified the transport method.  In other words, "I'm using Midas" doesn't tell me how you're getting the dataset from point A to point B.